# RecyclerView notifyItemInserted() Animation not showing when position is 0 but works fine with other position

Tags: android, android-animation, android-recyclerview

I am using

```
data.add(0,item);
notifyItemInserted(0);
```

This works fine as long as the items space is not filled up. After that, animation is not seen.

animation works fine when i do

```
data.add(1,item);
notifyItemInserted(1);
```

How to add items in 0 position and show animation all the time.  Do I have to use scrollToPosition?

Comment: can you please use notifydatasetchange() method insted of notifyItemInserted(0); my be it will work

Comment: @bhaveshkaila, notifydatasetchange() obviously works but kills the animation. actually, I need to show animation

Comment: @touchchandra did you find the solution

Answer (score 6):

call `scrollToPosition(0)` if you wan't it to scroll to position 0 after new item is added. RecyclerView will just keep the current top item in place, which is why you are not seeing the new item. (the new item is being added above the visible area).

Comment: I already tried using scrollToPosition(o) but the animation is very weird.Say, if I scroll to around 50th positions and add element to first position the animation to display the newly first item is really weird. i tried smootnScrollToPosition(0). Any workaround you have?

Comment: Do you really want the list to scroll to position 0 when user is already in position 50? It seems like a bad UX to me. In that case, you are better off using `smoothScrollToPosition` .