# adapter.notifyItemInserted(position == 0) not animating when using with linearLayoutManager.setreverselayout in android RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Here is the code of how I am updating the list and notify.

adapterlist = newlist;

and then I call notifyiteminserted(postionofinsertion);

I am using setReverseLayout(true) to make it a chat like RecyclerView;

My RV stays still, no change is visible. I need to scroll down to see the item.

Expectations -> If I am at the last item then item insert animation should happen and I am beyond the last item then nothing should happen.

notifyiteminserted(0) is not working. There is no change in the layout and di have to scroll down.
If I use notifyiteminserted(2 or 4) it works the animation is showing.

Comment: Maybe Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46296077/recyclerview-notifyiteminserted-not-updating-scrollbar

Comment: No. I am not using sethasfixedsize(true); Any other solutions?

Comment: Try manually scrolling to 0 Position.
mRecyclerView.postDelayed(() ->mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0), 200);

Comment: That is in my mind. but why 0 is not working and in other position it is working. Any Clue?

Comment: And I ahve to handle the case if the user is at suppose 50th position then don't scroll other conditions.

Comment: Just like in Chat Application. New Message comes with an animation.

Comment: I think that's the expected behavior for recyclerview. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31787725/6040079

For handling other positions you can get the current visiblePosition by 
currentPosition = mLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();